# How to send the json POST Request without body in ios?

Tags: ios, json

I want to send the post request without the body in ios

I tried as below

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some URL"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x15d62ed0 
NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x15e522a0 "Could not connect to the server."}
```

Comment: "Some URL" is not a valid URL! Have you tried posting something to the URL with another program to make sure that it is working?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *appurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some URL"];
appurl = [appurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appurl]];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString  *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

OR

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&pw=%@",[_txt_email.text lowercaseString],_txt_password.text];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login_new.php",app.Main_url]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: Tried first one but getting the same error
In second example we have to send the body.But my request is not having body.

Comment: can you try my first example >>>